# Key word ciphers

Tags: python, python-3.4

I've been trying for a long time to try and create a keyword cipher so that I can create a cipher app. however I cant seem to get it right, ive only been able to create a normal cipher can someone please change my code to a key word cipher

```
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
message = input('Please insert the message you want to encrypt: ')
key = int(input('What key value do you want in your encryption? '))

output = []

for m in message:
    if m in alphabet:
        output.append(alphabet[(alphabet.index(m) + key) % (len(alphabet))])

print(''.join(output))

message1 = input('please inset what you want to decrypt:')
key1 = int(input('please insert the key value wanted:'))

output = []

for m in message1:
    if m in alphabet:
        output.append(alphabet[(alphabet.index(m) - key1) % (len(alphabet))])


print(''.join(output))


print('thanks for coding!')
```

Comment: Related: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own

Comment: It seems you're referring to a Vigenere cipher, However, you haven't clarified what is giving you a hard time in implementing this. The general idea is that the key changes with each substitution, similar to the index of a letter in the alpabet; a concept that you have already used in your code.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must input a keyword and not a simple value, and store the values of each letter of the key in a list:

```
key1 = input('please insert the key value wanted:')
keys = [ alphabet.index(m) + 1 for m in key1 if m in alphabet ]
```

For example key `abc` would give `[1, 2, 3]`

Then you iterate over that list when computing the encoded string:

```
for i, m in enumerate(message):
    if m in alphabet:
        output.append(alphabet[(alphabet.index(m) + keys[i % len(keys)])
                                % (len(alphabet))])
```

And still same thing (with `- keys[...]` instead of `+ keys[...]`) for decoding, and it should work